# Should we embed virtual machines rather than languages

Tags: scripting, web-browser, virtual-machine

Ok, so I am trying to learn front-end programming. Trying to figure out how javascript is a pain, and various projects (GWT, Coffeescript, Capuccino's objective/j...) are trying to fix this with languages that compile to JS.

What would you do if you were to reinvent the browser?

I think I would embed a VM rather than a language (quite like Java applets except less complex and with a DOM API instead of a canvas and self-contained environment).

I suppose this has been suggested many times, but I cannot find resources on this, and most of the embedding tutorial I stumble on address embedding languages (guile, lua, python, whatever).

Thoughts?

Comment: Nowadays Javascript is pretty much a virtual machine on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An embedded language *IS* an embedded virtual machine, and vice versa.  Each has a defined interface to the browser, each has a defined user interface (syntax or instruction set or call it what you will).

If I were going to reinvent the browser, and provide a language for extensions, I would provide a LISP.  Most probably, I would look at a LISP based on GNU Emacs LISP (possibly GUILE?), because that particular LISP had certain scope and binding design decisions resolved in ways that allowed extensions to interoperate.

Why LISP?  In my personal opinion, LISP does some things easily that other languages do poorly or not at all.  It is perfectly feasible to compile procedural (more limited) languages to LISP, but, if you hit some of the corner cases, it can be very difficult to compile LISP to, say, C.